# Do save/restore affect clip() in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I tried to draw a "callout". When I called `clip()`, it seems to be affected by callout part.

Do `save()` and `restore()` not affect `clip()`?

```
canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  

//callout part
ctx.save();
ctx.moveTo(location[0].x, location[0].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[1].x, location[1].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[2].x, location[2].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[3].x, location[3].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[3].x, location[4].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[4].x, location[4].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[4].x, location[3].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[2].x, location[2].y);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

//text part
ctx.save();
ctx.rect(location[3].x, location[3].x, location[4].x - location[3].x, location[4].y - location[3].y);
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillText('test', location[3].x + 5 , location[3].y + 5);
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `save()` and `restore()` do save and restore the clipping regions, but what they do not is to save and restore the current sub-path declaration.

You need to call `ctx.beginPath()` before calling `rect()` or this rect will be added to the previous sub-path and all of it will be used for the clipping.

So this means that your first save/restore block is useless, since nothing it saves has been modified:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  

//callout part
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(location[0].x, location[0].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[1].x, location[1].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[2].x, location[2].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[3].x, location[3].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[3].x, location[4].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[4].x, location[4].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[4].x, location[3].y);
ctx.lineTo(location[2].x, location[2].y);
ctx.stroke();

//text part
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(location[3].x, location[3].x, location[4].x - location[3].x, location[4].y - location[3].y);
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillText('test', location[3].x + 5 , location[3].y + 5);
ctx.restore();
```